# Standardizing the JSON response

Tags: php, json

I have an application where information from the database is sent back as a JSON response.

Tailoring the jQuery side to handle each and every response seems like a lot of effort for little adaptability.

In what ways could the JSON format could be standardized ? Additionaly, is there a way to "slot in" a handler in jQuery ?

I've been thinking along the lines of something like this:

```
{
"replyCode": "OK"/"Error",
"replyMessage": "Operation successful"/"Could not connect",
"returnData": ... // Entities go here
}
```

Comment: Can you give us and example of code that does the job for one response, and talk a little about what the variance is among your responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standardizing the JSON response is something that needs to be customized for each application; only you have the necessary data to decide exactly what actions should be supported and how they would be communicated over JSON.

As an example, in the past I have used both a "response sniffer" logic (where the handler checks for specific properties in the response and processes each one that exists in a specific manner) and a "command list" logic (where the response always contains an array of objects that describe specific actions that must be taken and the handler executes them) in this situation.

I don't believe that a reply code and message is necessary in most situations as the HTTP response header can communicate this information effectively.

Whatever you decide to do, [`.ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) (and its siblings `.ajaxSuccess` and `.ajaxError`) can be used to install global response handlers on the client side that run on completion of every request.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should really take a look at the video [RESTful API Design](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpAhXa12xvU) from the apigee guys. It contains a ton of good advice for RESTful APIs. Brian Mulloy gives also feedback on how responses should look like.

Next, you should take a look at some libs in php for developing RESTful APIs. Some of these gives you a solid way of how to return responses.

- https://github.com/Respect/Rest
- https://github.com/MArcJ/PHPRestService
- https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord
- or more https://github.com/search?q=php%20rest

With this you should good to go to build well RESTful APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a central function that does the final echoing of the JSON as the response.

```
function returnJSON($code,$data=array()){
  echo json_encode(
    array(
      'replyCode'=>$code,
      'replyMessage'=>getReturnMessageByCode($code),
      'returnData'=>$data
    )
  );
}
```

Now at the end of every AJAX call you make to retrieve this data, your PHP code would do something like this -

```
$data = fetchData();
if ($data){
  returnJSON('OK',$data);
}else{
  returnJSON('FAIL');
}
exit();
```

Standardizing your responses is a great idea and is also your responsibility. Unless your framework has other options its up to *you* to make your code as robust as possible.